# Google Charts / visualisations column width

Tags: google-visualization

I am using the Google Chart API, and converted a line chart (see below) into a column chart, however the column widths change depending on the quantity of data columns. If I hover over, it tells me the correct date, however because of the changing width of the column you cannot actually accurately see the date the column should represent. A point would work, so I could revert to a line chart however, a column does look better for the data set I am using. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Date is dynamic, so the X axis has to be variable.

Thanks

```
// Create a line chart, passing some options
                var LineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
                    'containerId': 'chart_div',
                    'options': {
                        'vAxis': {'title': 'Species Abundance', 'minValue': 0, 'maxValue': 32},
                        'width': 300,
                        'height': 300,
                        'legend': 'top',           
                        'title': 'Selected Site and Species abundance over time'
                    },
                    'view': {'columns': [0, 1]},
                });
```

[image: Example Graphs]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set a maximum width by setting the `bar.groupWidth` option to an integer number (the number of pixels to use for a bar group).  Setting this option makes the API attempt to draw all bar groups (the set of bars at a given axis value) this width, though it may be forced to draw them smaller if the setup of the chart requires it.

```
bar: {
    groupWidth: 20
}
```

Comment: How to set max groupWidth for bar

Comment: Or you can set bar: {groupWidth: '50%'} if you want to use % instead of pixels

Comment: Spot on. Thanks. I will just mention that Bar property needs to be on the first level in the Options object so to say, next to the Title like so: 

var options = {
        title: "Text",
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"}
};

Initially I thought I had to put it under ‘hAxis’, which did not work