# Set bar width on ColumnChart from google chart in Java

Tags: java, google-visualization

I am having trouble setting the bar width on my bars in my ColumnChart.

So far I have the following options set:

```
private Options createOptions() {
        Options options = Options.create();
        options.setWidth(600);
        options.setHeight(400);
        options.set3D(true);
        options.setEnableTooltip(false);
        return options;
    }
```

But it seems like the option for setting the bar width is not there. If I set my width to 600 px, and only have 2 entries/bars, they will each be huge. If I have 10 it will look more normal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the documentation for this here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

The variable you'll want to be modifying is bar.groupWidth - you can set it to a size, or a percent ratio. So possibly something like this:

```
bar: {
    groupWidth: 20
}
```

See some other resources if you need more help:
[Google Charts / visualisations column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469213/google-charts-visualisations-column-width)

Here's another great set of posts:
http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/28797-bar-charts-bar-width/

Comment: but how would I do it in Java? you are refering to JS.
I have the following methods:
private Options createOptions() {
private AbstractDataTable createTable() {